# Is it possible to check if the function has a void return type

Tags: c++, c++11

This very strange request came up ...

I need to do a compile time check whether the current function has a `void` return type or not and fail compilation if the return type is `void`.

I tried to do some magic with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of and `decltype` also, however I just cannot get closer to a solution.

```
#include <type_traits>

void other_func(void) { }

void test_maxi(void)
{
    typedef decltype(&::other_func) TYPE;
    static_assert(std::is_same<TYPE, void>::value, "not void"); 
}

int main() {
}
```

So here comes the question:

Is it possible to do this for the **current function**?

**EDIT** The return type check should go in a macro, since it will be used in several functions.

Comment: Why? The compiler will already shout at you if you try to assign void to anything.

Comment: there is no such object as the current function, so how would you get the type?

Comment: maybe use lambda instead of traditional function?

Comment: Let it be the default value for a templated param of another function and call that function?

Comment: I suppose you get the same error as I do (see this [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebbb33fe34ce549c) example)

Comment: Why not use this static assert just after function definition, at global scope?

Comment: what if instead of `static_assert...` you write `TYPE var;`?

Comment: Do you want a solution that can be copied over (or macro'd in), i.e. without the need to type the function name and the parameter types (or sample values)?

Comment: @majk Yes, if possible :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can implement compile-time checking if one string literal starts with another, and use the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro, which is set to string literal that starts with function return type. You should check if this macro starts with `void` followed by space.

This code compiles fine:

```
constexpr bool startsWith(const char* a, const char* b) {
    return *a == *b && (*(a + 1) == '\0' || startsWith(a + 1, b + 1));
}

int f() {
    static_assert(!startsWith("void ", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__), "not void");
    return 1;
}


int main() {
}
```

If you change `f` return type to `void`:

```
constexpr bool startsWith(const char* a, const char* b) {
    return *a == *b && (*(a + 1) == '\0' || startsWith(a + 1, b + 1));
}

void f() {
    static_assert(!startsWith("void ", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__), "not void");
}


int main() {
}
```

`static_assert` will fire.

The `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro seems to be specific to GNU C++ Compiler, however, `clang++` works fine since it defines this macro as well. If you are using another compiler, you should check if this macro is really being set, and if not, read compiler documentation in order to determine similar
macro, e.g., `__FUNCSIG__`.

You can play around with `#ifdef __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ...` to make this more portable between various compilers, but I believe this is a topic for another question.

Comment: Based on the strange requirement of making this a macro (yuck) this is the correct answer. Side note: For Visual C++ you can use `__FUNCSIG__`.

Comment: Very nice. Let me add that you should check it to start with "void ", to avoid firing on methods returning `void*` or a custom struct `voidfoo`.

Comment: `namespace{void _(){\n #ifdef __PRETTY_FUNC__\n #define BOB 1 #else #define BOB 2 #endif }}` should get you `BOB` token that distinguishes between pretty func or funcsig.  With some playing around, shoud be able to define a token that is `__PRETTY_FUNC__` iff it would be valid...

Answer (score 6):

If you can name the current function then the simplest way is:

```
static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(test_maxi()), void>::value, "void");
```

Comment: This is a small problem ... I cannot name the current function, this is supposed to go in a macro kind of construct.

Comment: @fritzone If you can mark your function as `constexpr`, this will work.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
template <typename ... Args>
constexpr bool return_void(void(Args ...)) { return true; }

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
constexpr bool return_void(R(Args ...)) { return false; }
```

Let's suppose we have the following functions:

```
void f() {}
void g(int) {}
void h(int*,char&) {}
void i(float,bool) {}
void j(const char *const) {}
void k(void()) {}
int l() { return {}; }
float m(int) { return {}; }
```

All the calls to `return_void` will return true as long as it is called with the first six functions, the `return_void(l)` and `return_void(m)` call will return false because they will invoke the second version of the template, the one returning false.

<kbd>[Check it online](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Gl3CXI8Paf4C3I59)</kbd>

This will allow you to check if a function return `void` both at runtime and compile time:

```
int main() {
    static_assert(return_void(f), "not void");

    if (!return_void(m))
        std::cout << "m result is: " << m(0) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the return type of the current function by checking whether a dead `return` can compile:

```
struct ConvertToAnything {
    template <class T>
    operator T() const { assert(!"Don't call me!"); }
};

#define CHECK_NONVOID_RETURN() if(true); else return ConvertToAnything{}

int f() {
    CHECK_NONVOID_RETURN(); // Passes
    return 42;
}

void g() {
    CHECK_NONVOID_RETURN(); // Fails at compile-time
}
```

The case of `void` is a special one, so this is enough. But you can also forbid other types by overloading `ConvertToAnything::operator Type() = delete;`. Allowing `void` is a bit more involved, but still feasible.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to detect the return type and check if it is of type void. To check the type you can use `std::is_void`. return type can be detected with following template:

```
#include <type_traits> // for is_void

template<typename R, typename... A>
void test(R (*func)(A...)) {
   static_assert(
       !std::is_void<R>::value, 
       "void return type is not allowed"
   ); 
}

// functions to check:
void a(int, char*) {}
int b(char, float) {return 0;}

int main()
{
    test(a); // < assert triggered here
    test(b);
}
```